# Expo set notification to a specific datetime

Tags: react-native, expo

In Expo docs there is this example to show a notification after 60 seconds.

```
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';

Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
  content: {
    title: "Time's up!",
    body: 'Change sides!',
  },
  trigger: {
    seconds: 60,
  },
});
```

But how can I show a notification in a specific date for example at `08/28/2022 08:30AM`

Comment: The trigger has a date property, try specifying it

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick example of how to use the date property as Dmitro_ specified in the comment. It's actually [DateTriggerInput](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#datetriggerinput) notification type and you can use it as follows:

```
let date = new Date();
//Add 10 seconds to the current date to test it.
date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + 10);

await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
  content: {...},
  trigger: { date: date},
});
```